# Whois Lookup in CSV

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

I have about 9000 IPs and need to store that data for research purposes.
I am trying to store these IPs data in CSV files by the whois command

I am looing : 1st row should be header-only, (that I can also do manually as well) and the second row must contain the output in a row (here I stuck).

My Code:

```
while read -r ip; do

whois $ip | grep : | tr -d : | rs -T | tr -s ' ' , >> output.csv

done < "ip.txt"
```

By the above command, data is a store but in multiple lines.

Sample output

```
%   refer   status  %   -   Co. Ltd.    CN  ALLOCATED   last-modified   China   IP50-AP CNNIC   remarks remarks the role    phone   nic-hdl abuse-mailbox   person  District    Beijing lwz@knet.cn APNIC   Zhongguancun    Haidian e-mail  source  Co. Ltd.    MAINT-CNNIC-AP
for whois.apnic.net ALLOCATED   Whois   1.8.255.255 descr   admin-c PORTABLE    2021-06-16T013150Z  e-mail  auth    is  empowered   Please  network.    ABUSE   0   AC1601-AP   ipas@cnnic.cn   Wenzhe  country nic-hdl person  District    Beijing xingzhijie@knet.cn  APNIC   country last-modified           
more    inetnum whois   data    netname 4   South   ZX2975-AP   mnt-by  source  ipas@cnnic.cn   #   not to  contact mnt-by  CNNICCN e-mail  remarks mnt-by  Lu  CN  WL1818-AP   Zhijie  country nic-hdl route   CN  2011-06-29T014602Z          
information 1.0.0.0 whois.apnic.net copyright   KNET    4th tech-c  MAINT-CNNIC-AP  APNIC   abuse-mailbox   Filtered    an  investigate the MAINT-CNNIC-AP  address ipas@cnnic.cn   Generated   APNIC-ABUSE address phone   mnt-by  Xing    CN  ZX2975-AP   1.8.0.0/16  origin  source              
on  -   changed terms   descr   treet   WL1818-AP   mnt-routes  irt ipas@cnnic.cn   remarks ISP complaints  tech-c  last-modified   Beijing admin-c from    last-modified   4   South   -58812941   MAINT-CNNIC-AP  address phone   mnt-by  descr   AS38345 APNIC           
IANA    1.255.255.255   2010-01 http//www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html KNET    Zhongguancun    Haidian abuse-c MAINT-CNNIC-AP  IRT-CNNIC-CN    admin-c Please  and of  or  2021-06-16T013957Z  China   IP50-AP irt 2020-05-14T111901Z  4th fax-no  last-modified   4   South   -58812398   MAINT-CNNIC-AP  KNET    notify          
visit   organisation    source  inetnum Techonlogy  District    Beijing AC1601-AP   mnt-irt address IP50-AP note    is  network admin-c source  country tech-c  object  source  treet   -58812716   2011-03-16T033202Z  4th fax-no  last-modified   Techonlogy  lwz@knet.cn             
http//www.iana.org  APNIC   IANA    1.8.19.0    (BeiJing)   country status  IRT-CNNIC-CN    Beijing tech-c  that    not abuse.  of  APNIC   ZZ  IP50-AP IRT-CNNIC-CN    APNIC   Zhongguancun    Haidian e-mail  source  treet   -58812716   2014-07-23T030801Z  (BeiJing)   mnt-by              
%   refer   status  %   -   Co. Ltd.    CN  ALLOCATED   last-modified   China   IP50-AP CNNIC   remarks remarks the role    phone   nic-hdl abuse-mailbox   person  District    Beijing lwz@knet.cn APNIC   Zhongguancun    Haidian e-mail  source  Co. Ltd.    MAINT-CNNIC-AP
for whois.apnic.net ALLOCATED   Whois   1.8.255.255 descr   admin-c PORTABLE    2021-06-16T013150Z  e-mail  auth    is  empowered   Please  network.    ABUSE   0   AC1601-AP   ipas@cnnic.cn   Wenzhe  country nic-hdl person  District    Beijing xingzhijie@knet.cn  APNIC   country last-modified           
more    inetnum whois   data    netname 4   South   ZX2975-AP   mnt-by  source  ipas@cnnic.cn   #   not to  contact mnt-by  CNNICCN e-mail  remarks mnt-by  Lu  CN  WL1818-AP   Zhijie  country nic-hdl route   CN  2011-06-29T014602Z          
information 1.0.0.0 whois.apnic.net copyright   KNET    4th tech-c  MAINT-CNNIC-AP  APNIC   abuse-mailbox   Filtered    an  investigate the MAINT-CNNIC-AP  address ipas@cnnic.cn   Generated   APNIC-ABUSE address phone   mnt-by  Xing    CN  ZX2975-AP   1.8.0.0/16  origin  source              
on  -   changed terms   descr   treet   WL1818-AP   mnt-routes  irt ipas@cnnic.cn   remarks ISP complaints  tech-c  last-modified   Beijing admin-c from    last-modified   4   South   -58812941   MAINT-CNNIC-AP  address phone   mnt-by  descr   AS38345 APNIC           
IANA    1.255.255.255   2010-01 http//www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html KNET    Zhongguancun    Haidian abuse-c MAINT-CNNIC-AP  IRT-CNNIC-CN    admin-c Please  and of  or  2021-06-16T013957Z  China   IP50-AP irt 2020-05-14T111901Z  4th fax-no  last-modified   4   South   -58812398   MAINT-CNNIC-AP  KNET    notify          
visit   organisation    source  inetnum Techonlogy  District    Beijing AC1601-AP   mnt-irt address IP50-AP note    is  network admin-c source  country tech-c  object  source  treet   -58812716   2011-03-16T033202Z  4th fax-no  last-modified   Techonlogy  lwz@knet.cn             
http//www.iana.org  APNIC   IANA    1.8.19.0    (BeiJing)   country status  IRT-CNNIC-CN    Beijing tech-c  that    not abuse.  of  APNIC   ZZ  IP50-AP IRT-CNNIC-CN    APNIC   Zhongguancun    Haidian e-mail  source  treet   -58812716   2014-07-23T030801Z  (BeiJing)   mnt-by
```

---

ip.txt

```
1.8.65.98
1.8.65.99
1.8.65.92
1.82.15.99
11.18.65.19
111.8.65.99
1.18.65.91
1.81.65.99
1.8.15.99
1.8.61.99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
whois 1.1.1.1 | grep ": " | awk -F": " '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ','  >> result.csv

while read -r ip; do

wip=$(whois $ip | grep ": " | awk -F": " '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ',' )

echo $ip,$wip >> result.csv

done < "ip.txt"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You never need `grep` or `tr` when you're using awk, you should always use `IFS=` in a shell while-read loop unless you need to not use it, and you should always quote your shell variables unless you need to not quote them.